# Retrofit query with hashmap parameters of comma separated list java

Tags: java, dictionary, retrofit

I am trying to use the Kasses Spotify web api to get a series of recommended songs for the user. In the get request the there are two arguments a map and a call back. For the callback all good. But for the map I am not sure how to format the parameters.

This is the documentation:

> ```
> @GET(value="/recommendations")
> void getRecommendations(@QueryMap
>                           Map<String,Object> options,
>                           retrofit.Callback<Recommendations> callback)
> Create a playlist-style listening experience based on seed artists, tracks and genres.
> Parameters:
> options - Optional parameters. For list of available parameters see endpoint documentation
> callback - callback method
> ```

it says the parameters (options) are in the format Map and it points to the endpoint documentation for the  parameters  here:

https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/get-recommendations/

So I can see that some are optional and some are required. One example of a required one is here:

```
Argument:
seed_genres 

Value:
A comma separated list of any genres in the set of available genre seeds.
```

So I am for my map in the form of:

```
Map <String, Object>
```

I am guessing String would be "seed_genres"

But for the object I am not sure how to format that:

For example if I was looking at reggae, jazz, metal.

How do I make that a comma separated list even if it is a String object I am still not sure how to format that.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Try `options.put("seed_genres", "reggae,jazz,metal")`

Comment: That was it! Thank you. Wow was I over thinking it! Thanks again